# A property of uniform spaces

Tags: relations, uniform-spaces

Is it true that $E\circ E\subseteq E$ for every entourage $E$ of every uniform space?

Comment: I'm not quite sure about your notation, but I would assume that $$E\circ E = \{(x,z): \exists\, y\text{ such that } (x,y), (y,z)\in E\}.$$
So your inclusion should go the other way: $E\subseteq E\circ E$, since the diagonal $\Delta \subset X\times X$ is always a subset of $E$.

Comment: Obviously not true, as every entourage is reflexive, the inclusion is the other way around.

Comment: It easy to see that $E\circ E\subseteq E$ holds for uniformities induced by metric spaces.

Answer (score 2):

As noted in the comments, it clearly is not true in general.

If an entourage $E$ has the property that $E\circ E\subseteq E$, then $E$ is a transitive, reflexive relation on $X$, and the entourage $E\cap E^{-1}$ is an equivalence relation on $X$. A uniform space whose uniformity has a base of equivalence relations is *non-Archimedean*, the uniform analogue of a [non-Archimedean metric space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultrametric_space); such a space is zero-dimensional, since it clearly has a base of clopen sets. Conversely, it’s known that every zero-dimensional topology is induced by a non-Archimedean uniformity. (I’ve seen this last result cited to B. Banaschewski, *Über nulldimensionale Räume*, Math. Nachr. $\bf13$ ($1955$), $129$-$140$, and to A.F. Monna, *Remarques sur les métriques non-archimédiennes*, Indag. Math. $\bf12$ ($1950$), $122$-$133$; ibid. $\bf12$ ($1950$), $179$-$191$, but I’ve not seen these papers.)