# Non-archimedean uniform space

Tags: general-topology, reference-request, uniform-spaces

I know about uniform spaces and read this question:

[A property of uniform spaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/402231/a-property-of-uniform-spaces/402302?r=SearchResults#402302)

Now I am very curious and I would like to learn more about these non-Archimedean uniform spaces.

For instance, I am wondering if all non-Archimedean uniformities come from systems of non-Archimedean pseudo-metrics. Or am I wrong with this conjecture?

Can anybody give me some references for this topic where the basic observations are written down?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the book ***Non-Archimedean functional analysis*** by van Rooij, Arnoud CM, New York: Dekker, 1978, there is a section on Non-archimedean uniform spaces on pages 34-38.
In particular, on page 38, provides a list of references that discuss the problem of ultrametrizability of uniform spaces.

[image: References 84, 85]
[image: Reference 158]
[image: Reference 181]
[image: References 183-184]

Enjoy!