# Is every zero-dimensional metrisable space ultrametrisable?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, uniform-spaces, ultrametric

Let us recall a few definitions. A topological space is

- *metrisable* if it is homeomorphic to a metric space.
- *ultrametrisable* if it is homeomorphic to an [ultrametric space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultrametric_space).
- *zero-dimensional* if every point has a basis of clopen neighbourhoods.
- *strongly zero-dimensional* if for each closed subset $F$ and each neighbourhood $U$ of $F$, there is a clopen neighbourhood of $F$ contained in $U$.

**Question**. Is every zero-dimensional metrisable space ultrametrisable?

If I am not mistaken, this is true for compact spaces and more generally, for [Lindelöf spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindel%C3%B6f_space). For the general case,
according to an exercise in Bourbaki [General topology, Chapter 9], a metrisable space is ultrametrisable if and only if it is strongly zero-dimensional. Moreover, it is added in a footnote that it is not known whether every zero-dimensional metrisable space is strongly zero-dimensional.

Thus the problem was apparently open when Bourbaki published his volume on general topology, but I wonder whether it has been solved since then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Prabir Roy, *Nonequality of Dimensions for Metric Spaces*,  Transactions of the American Mathematical Society
Vol. 134, No. 1 (Oct., 1968), pp. 117-132, available [here](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1968-134-01/S0002-9947-1968-0227960-2/S0002-9947-1968-0227960-2.pdf) [PDF], has a complicated construction (which I have not gone through) of a complete metric space that is zero-dimensional but not strongly zero-dimensional.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I accept your answer immediately, but indeed the construction in the paper looks particularly complicated.

Comment: @J.-E.Pin: You’re welcome! Yes, it looks downright formidable, though I suspect that the proof that the space is not strongly zero-dimensional may be worse.

Comment: Browsing on this site, I just discovered a [possibly related answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3333962) to my question. Anyway, I will have a look at the given references.

Comment: If you want, there are also other examples of similar spaces built afterwards, e.g. Kulesza - An example in the dimension theory of metrizable spaces (1990) ([link](https://tinyurl.com/ypk26p5t)).