# Can all the entourages of a uniform structure be transitive?

Tags: general-topology, topological-groups, uniform-spaces

A uniform structure $\Phi$ on a set $X$ is a collection of relations that satisfy [some special properties.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_space#Entourage_definition)

- In general, all relations must be reflexive.
- For metric spaces all the relations are symmetric too.

Also, the axiom $\forall U\in\Phi \exists V\in\Phi : V\circ V\subseteq U$ quite closer to being transitive, but not exactly that.
I am wondering if there is some uniform structure in which all the relations are transitive. i.e., $\forall U\in\Phi\rightarrow U\circ U\subseteq U.$

1. If not, why?
2. If yes, what would be the consequences of this special property? And can I see an example?

Comment: I guess non-Archimedean metric spaces are examples.

Comment: Also, check out https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/402231/a-property-of-uniform-spaces/402302#402302

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your claim concerning metric spaces is wrong.
Let $\cal U$ be the uniformity associated with a metric space $X$. If $U$ is a relation of $\cal U$, then $U^{-1}$ is in $\cal U$. Thus the symmetric relation $U \cap U^{-1}$ also belongs to $\cal U$. Consequently, the uniformity $\cal U$ is *generated* by the symmetric relations of $\cal U$, but there are in general non-symmetric relations in $\cal U$.

Coming back to your question, suppose that all the relations in $\cal U$ are transitive and suppose that $X$ contains three distinct elements $a, b, c$. Let
$$
U = \{(x,y) \in X \times X \mid d(x,y) < d(a,c)/2\} \text{ and } V = U \cup \{(a,b), (b,c)\}
$$
Then $U$ is an entourage and so is $V$, since it contains $U$. Now, as $V$ is transitive, one also has $(a, c) \in V$ and hence $(a, c) \in U$, a contradiction. It follows that $X$ contains at most two elements !

A uniformity is called *transitive* if it is *generated* by transitive entourages. This is an interesting notion, which, as mentioned in the comments, is the uniform analog of an ultrametric, like the $p$-adic metric.